# User notifications (local) rescheduled?

Tags: ios, notifications, unusernotificationcenter

If I schedule a local notification with unusernotificationcenter and the user then disables notifications for my app then my notification will not be delivered. This is clear.

But if the user then allows notifications for my app will the notification that was scheduled previously be delivered at the alarm trigger in the future?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Just tried verified it in my own app.